# How to prevent that empty Object overwrites user input in field in Vue.js

Tags: typescript, forms, vue.js

This is my current code:

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Deutsch</h3>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-2">
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.titleDe')"
          v-model="formData.title.de"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.title.de.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.title.de.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:title', formData.title)"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.teaserTextDe')"
          v-model="formData.teaserText.de"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.teaserText.de.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.teaserText.de.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:teaserText', formData.teaserText)"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.linkUrlDe')"
          v-model="formData.linkUrl.de"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.linkUrl.de.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.linkUrl.de.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:linkUrl', formData.linkUrl)"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.linkTitleDe')"
          v-model="formData.linkTitle.de"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.linkTitle.de.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.linkTitle.de.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:linkTitle', formData.linkUrl)"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="mt-3">Francais</h3>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-2">
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.titleFr')"
          v-model="formData.title.fr"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.title.fr.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.title.fr.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:title', formData.title)"
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.teaserTextFr')"
          v-model="formData.teaserText.fr"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.teaserText.fr.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.teaserText.fr.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:teaserText', formData.teaserText)"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.linkUrlFr')"
          v-model="formData.linkUrl.fr"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.linkUrl.fr.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.linkUrl.fr.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:linkUrl', formData.linkUrl)"
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.linkTitleFr')"
          v-model="formData.linkTitle.fr"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.linkTitle.fr.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.linkTitle.fr.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:linkTitle', formData.linkTitle)"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="mt-3">Italiano</h3>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-2">
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.titleIt')"
          v-model="formData.title.it"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.title.it.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.title.it.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:title', formData.title)"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.teaserTextIt')"
          v-model="formData.teaserText.it"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.teaserText.it.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.teaserText.it.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:teaserText', formData.teaserText)"
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.linkUrlIt')"
          v-model="formData.linkUrl.it"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.linkUrl.it.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.linkUrl.it.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:linkUrl', formData.linkUrl)"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.linkTitleIt')"
          v-model="formData.linkTitle.it"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.linkTitle.it.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.linkTitle.it.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:linkTitle', formData.linkTitle)"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="mt-3">English</h3>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-2">
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.titleEn')"
          v-model="formData.title.en"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.title.en.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.title.en.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:title', formData.title)"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.teaserTextEn')"
          v-model="formData.teaserText.en"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.teaserText.en.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.teaserText.en.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:teaserText', formData.teaserText)"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.linkUrlEn')"
          v-model="formData.linkUrl.en"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.linkUrl.en.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.linkUrl.en.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:linkUrl', formData.linkUrl)"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Input
          :label="$t('pageHeroSectionNew.linkTitleEn')"
          v-model="formData.linkTitle.en"
          :error="
            formDataValidation.linkTitle.en.$errors
              .map((error) => $t(error.$message.toString()))
              .toString()
          "
          @blur="formDataValidation.linkTitle.en.$touch"
          @input="$emit('update:linkTitle', formData.linkTitle)"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div>
    <blockquote class="image-wrapper">
      <p class="warning" v-if="!thumbnailUrl">
        {{ $t('rsNewsForm.noThumbnail') }}
      </p>
      <img v-if="thumbnailUrl" :src="thumbnailUrl" class="image" />
    </blockquote>
    <br />
    <br />
    <RsSingleImagePicker @upload="onThumbnailChange"></RsSingleImagePicker>
  </div>
  <br />

  <Button class="mr-2 secondary" @click="router.push(cancelUrl)">{{
    $t('pageGoodsGroupNew.cancel')
  }}</Button>
  <Button @click="onFormSubmit" :disabled="isSubmitting">{{
    $t('pageGoodsGroupNew.submit')
  }}</Button>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import useVuelidate from '@vuelidate/core'
import { required, requiredIf } from '@vuelidate/validators'
import { computed, defineAsyncComponent, ref } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const RsSingleImagePicker = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('./RsSingleImagePicker.vue'),
)

const router = useRouter()

const cancelUrl = '/cms/hero-section'

const props = defineProps<{
  title: {
    de: string
    fr: string
    it: string
    en: string
  }
  teaserText: {
    de: string
    fr: string
    it: string
    en: string
  }
  linkUrl: {
    de: string
    fr: string
    it: string
    en: string
  }
  linkTitle: {
    de: string
    fr: string
    it: string
    en: string
  }
  image: File | undefined
}>()
const emit = defineEmits([
  'update:title',
  'update:teaserText',
  'update:linkUrl',
  'update:linkTitle',
  'update:image',
  'cancel',
  'submit',
])

const formData = ref({
  title: { de: '', fr: '', it: '', en: '' },
  teaserText: { de: '', fr: '', it: '', en: '' },
  linkUrl: { de: '', fr: '', it: '', en: '' },
  linkTitle: { de: '', fr: '', it: '', en: '' },
  image: '',
})

const formDataValidation = useVuelidate(
  {
    title: {
      de: {
        required: {
          $validator: required.$validator,
          $message: 'validations.required',
        },
      },
      fr: {},
      it: {},
      en: {},
    },
    teaserText: {
      de: {},
      fr: {},
      it: {},
      en: {},
    },
    linkUrl: {
      de: {
        requiredIfLinkTitleDe: requiredIf(formData.value.linkTitle.de),
      },
      fr: {},
      it: {},
      en: {},
    },
    linkTitle: {
      de: {
        requiredIfLinkUrlDe: requiredIf(formData.value.linkUrl.de),
      },
      fr: {},
      it: {},
      en: {},
    },

    image: {
      required: {
        $validator: required.$validator,
        $message: 'validations.required',
      },
      isBase64: {
        $validator: isBase64,
        $message: 'validations.isBase64',
      },
    },
  },
  formData,
)

function isBase64(value: string) {
  return /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})$/.test(
    value,
  )
}
**
const isSubmitting = ref(false)

const onFormSubmit = async () => {
  const isStepValid = await required.$validator
  if (!isStepValid) return
  isSubmitting.value = true
  emit('submit', {
    title: {
      de: {},
      fr: {},
      it: {},
      en: {},
    },
    teaserText: {
      de: {},
      fr: {},
      it: {},
      en: {},
    },
    linkUrl: {
      de: {},
      fr: {},
      it: {},
      en: {},
    },
    linkTitle: {
      de: {},
      fr: {},
      it: {},
      en: {},
    },
    image: isBase64,
  })
}**

const thumbnailUrl = computed({
  get() {
    return props.image ? URL.createObjectURL(props.image) : ''
  },
  set(value) {
    return value
  },
})
const onThumbnailChange = (image: File) => {
  console.log(image)
  thumbnailUrl.value = URL.createObjectURL(image)
  console.log(thumbnailUrl.value)
  emit('update:image', image)
}
</script>
```

I think the problem occurs in the onFormSubmit function. When I log the output through the index.ts (where I define the logic) of what's in the created Form, all values are: "{}". The values that were written into the inputfields are overwritten by the emit function. (That's what my assumption is).

I've tried putting String, '' and alike in the place of {}. But none of that worked.

Comment: Hi!
Could you please reduce your example to be a more concise one?

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is your path